# How does precomputing the function selector save gas?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

In the [Solidity by example function Selector example](https://solidity-by-example.org/function-selector/),
it mentions that:

> Perhaps you can save a tiny amount of gas if you precompute and inline the function selector in your code?

I have a couple questions:

1. How does precomputing the function selector save gas?

Is it because you avoid calling `FunctionSelector.getSelector` and since [each function call costs gas](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf#page=27)(`txdatanonzero`)? The less functions you call the less your gas costs?

2. Where is this `FunctionSelector` implemented? Do we need to add it to our Smart contract or is it available automatically?
3. If it's available automatically, how do we avoid calling `getSelector`? I'm assuming it's automatically called when you execute a function call on a transaction so how do you avoid it?

```
contract FunctionSelector {
    /*
    "transfer(address,uint256)"
    0xa9059cbb
    "transferFrom(address,address,uint256)"
    0x23b872dd
    */
    function getSelector(string calldata _func) external pure returns (bytes4) {
        return bytes4(keccak256(bytes(_func)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The cited sentence probably has a slightly different meaning.
By "precomputing and inlining" they meant to literally precompute the value and inserting it into the smart contract before deploying it:

```
"transfer(address,uint256)" => 0xa9059cbb
```

It only applies to cases where you are always calling the same function.

As per the solidity documentation, function selector is the first 4 calldata bytes, then starting from the 5th byte, encoded arguments follow.
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/abi-spec.html

Not going to provide a functioning solution here, but sure there's a way to encode only the parameters and append them to the precomputed function selector (data is shorter, should be cheaper?).

The `getSelector(string calldata _func)` is just a concrete implementation how the function selector is calculated on chain.

Comment: Thanks Stanislav!